# Remove some word/string from a regular expression pattern

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector with the following values:

```
list <- c("test_data", "train_data", "random_forest_output", "xgboost_output", "light_gbm_output", "all_output", "all_output_final")
```

I need to select all variables that contain `"output"` word, but in the case of values `"all_output"` and `"all_output_final"` I need to choose only the `"all_output_final"`.
That is, I need to get a list like this:

```
new_list <- c("random_forest_output", "xgboost_output", "light_gbm_output", "all_output_final")
```

Is it possible to implement using a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it's misleading to other users to call a data object `list` For one thing `list` is an important R function and for another your object "list" is not an R list. That said it's pretty easy to do this with logical values returned from the regex function `grepl` by using &! to eliminate the unwanted pattern which is denoted regex-ly by including the end of string `"$"`

```
list[ grepl("output", list)&!grepl("^all_output$",list)]
[1] "random_forest_output" "xgboost_output"       "light_gbm_output"     "all_output_final"
```

You could read that `&!` (and NOT) expression as "... all of the preceding stuff  but nonone of the following matches"